# Why does Samsung's Always On Display not work on some not so old Galaxy devices?

Tags: samsung, 7.0-nougat, 8.0-oreo

Samsung's Always On Display (AOD) has minimum and targeted API 24 i.e. Android Nougat 7.0. It runs on all the latest Galaxy smartphones including, but not limited, to A5 (2017), A7 (2017) and even the much older devices - S6 and S7.

My Galaxy A9 Pro (2016) got updated to Android Oreo 8.0 today with no AOD whatsoever. It had Marshmallow out of the box (S6 had Lollipop). So, I tried sideloading the AOD's untouched APK I obtained from a trusted source. It failed to install, without giving any error message.

Whereas, on the previous Nougat 7.0 OS, I had successfully sideloaded the APK though it never worked. Also apparently there already exists a package with the same name as the APK I try to sideload but maybe it is disabled permanently. So, the quick-install-after-a-reboot trick worked sometimes. It did add the Always on Display option in the Settings app but it always crashed when opened.

What's the reason behind this behaviour? An app which is supposed to run on lower API 24, doesn't work on API 26 even though the manufacturer is same and the hardware isn't much different than the above listed Galaxy smartphones.

Comment: Just a guess, but it could be that there's a Samsung-specific API that is not implemented on Galaxy A9 Pro, which makes it crashes when accessed (are you able to get the log using ADB/logcat?). Unfortunately, I don't know much about how Samsung's customization works...